# WooCommerce custom payment gateway

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm trying to write a WooCommerce plugin for a client's website that they're going to be selling subscriptions to customers. I've been exploring my options and the best one I can come up with is to roll my own payment gateway module to handle this. (Other advice appreciated if anyone's ever tackled something like this).

However, I'm trying to add a custom payment gateway, but it doesn't seem to be working up. It's not showing up under `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Payment Gateways`. The plugin is installed and activated in WordPress, and I've followed a [couple](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/) [guides](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin-base/) [from](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-integration-guide/) their docs pages.

- WooCommerce version: 2.0.18 (via plugin installer)
- [gist code](https://gist.github.com/Genesis2001/7f2ed7b4d31230e52a8f)

I really don't know why or what would cause my payment gateway isn't showing up.

Thanks for the future help.

Comment: Did you implement woocommerce_payment_gateways filter? Is your class' PHP file loaded, or autoloaded? Have you looked at your error log to see if anything is being logged?

Comment: The gist link shows that I have used `woocommerce_payment_gateways` filter. The php file is loaded manually from in the plugin file. I'm unsure how to even use autoloading in PHP. I'll take a look at the error log when I get home today.

Comment: On a side note, I also found "WooSponsorship" plugin linked on this site and downloaded it from github and it's stripe gateway doesn't even load the gateway. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so the gist is your code; from your description I thought it was someone else's code you read for inspiration.

Your woostripe.php file, which loads your gateway class, bails out before loading the gateway class:

```
// bail on constructor if gateway class isn't loaded!
if (!class_exists('WooStripe_Gateway')) return;
// ...  
// why are you attempting to load WooCommerce's classes? Don't!
include_once(dirname(plugin_basename('woocommerce.php')) . 'classese/abstracts/abstract-wc-payment-gateway.php');
// never gets here to load this class, you've already left this function...
include_once(dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . 'classes/WooStripe_Gateway.php');
```

Remove the include statement for WooCommerce's class, that's WooCommerce's job not yours. Then move your WooStripe_Gateway include to the top of `woocommerce_gateway_init()` **before** the test to see if it exists. That class cannot exist until it is loaded.

Comment: A note, thanks for the help. I ended up going with the easier, albeit more expensive option due to time constraints. Thanks though!